# What is wrong with my method of implementing a predicate?

Tags: c++

```
vector<pair<string, long> > probLabel;
max_element(probLabel.begin(), probLabel.end(), vectPairMax)->first
```

probLabel contains a label and a number for it. I'm trying to get the largest number in probLabel and return the label. So I'm using max_element and wrote a predicate function.

```
bool vectPairMax(const pair<string, int> &lhs, const pair<string, int> &rhs) {
 if (lhs.second < rhs.second) {
    return true;
 } else {
    return false;
 }
}
```

Is this a functor or a function pointer that I am writing? In either case I don't see how it is wrong. Perhaps if it is a function pointer do I need to dereference it? Any suggestions in general would be greatly appreciated

This is the error message:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ProbCalc(DataAllFive&, std::__1::map, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::less, std::__1::allocator > >, std::__1::allocator, std::__1::allocator > const, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > > > >&, std::__1::set, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::less, std::__1::allocator > >, std::__1::allocator, std::__1::allocator > > >)", referenced from:
      PredictionTest(csvstream&, DataAllFive&) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Complete Condensed Code

```
string ProbCalc(Data &trainData, map<string, string> &tempMap2, set<string> &uniqueWords) {
   vector<pair<string, int> > probLabel; // Vector of pairs of labels and their probability.    
   // Iterate through all known posts in training data
   for (auto foo : trainData.postNum) {
      probLabel.push_back(make_pair(foo, 0));
   }
   // Label
   string mostProbPost = max_element(probLabel.begin(), probLabel.end(), vectPairMax)->first;

   return mostProbPost;
}


// Predicate for max_element function
bool vectPairMax(const pair<string, int> &lhs, const pair<string, int> &rhs) {
   if (lhs.second < rhs.second) {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] including the actual and the desired behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The only problem is I did not include the error message which I will add shortly

Comment: Two isolated code fragments aren't anywhere what's needed for a "complete" example.

Comment: Putting the rest of the code would be pointless and is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: You didn't say why you think it's "wrong". What is the actual problem?

Comment: @OkIsayHi: _"Putting the rest of the code would be pointless and is irrelevant to the problem"_ If I had a dime for every time someone said that, when they had a problem that _they_ couldn't figure out (!), then the problem ended up being in the "irrelevant" code... that is why a [MCVE] is a **requirement**. So simply post one now, instead of arguing. You were already instructed to do this by the Help Centre and the Tour. Plus, if you haven't constructed an MCVE yet, then you have not finished your own debugging before asking for help.

Comment: I added in the rest of the code and stripped out a few lines

Comment: `do stuff` is not valid c++ - there's your problem right there.

Comment: @RichardHodges if you don't want to help then that's fine

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How is the rest more relevant?

Comment: @OkIsayHi I have posted an MCVE for you as an answer. What it shows is that there is actually no problem with the predicate. The problem is elsewhere. This is why an MCVE is so important. We can't help you if you don't help us. We're not trying to be mean.

Comment: @OkIsayHi: We don't know, without seeing your MCVE. That's the point. You should learn how to follow basic instructions.

Comment: @RichardHodges I'm happy that's the case. Knowing that my hypothesis of where the problem was is very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the predicate. This compiles fine:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool vectPairMax(const std::pair<std::string, int> &lhs, const std::pair<std::string, int> &rhs) 
{
if (lhs.second < rhs.second) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> > probLabel;
    std::string mostProbPost = max_element(probLabel.begin(), probLabel.end(), vectPairMax)->first;

}
```